# How to disable row selection in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagridview

I currently have a DataGrid in WPF and it automatically highlights the first row of the grid (shown in attached picture). Is there a way to disable the auto highlight of the first row.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try this:

```
<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = "False" ...>
```

If that doesn't work, then you can try to disable focus:

Like this:

```
<Style x:Key="UnfocusableRow" TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
</Style>

<DataGridTextColumn RowStyle="{StaticResource UnfocusableRow}" />
```

Or:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

But you should be aware that if you turn off focus, you won't be able to see or select rows in the data grid.
if you want to select rows in the data grid, the focus off option will not work for you.